# How to calculate the number of loyal customers per city based on their order distribution in ClickHouse

Tags: sql, polygon, clickhouse

I have two tables in ClickHouse: districts and orders. The districts table contains information about specific districts on a map, including the district name, district ID, city ID, and polygon data. The orders table contains customer orders, including customer ID, latitude, and longitude.

I want to calculate the following metrics for each customer within a specific time period:

- Total number of orders placed by the customer.
- Number of orders placed by the customer in each city.

Additionally, I would like to determine the number of loyal customers per city, where a loyal customer is defined as someone who has placed more than 50% of their orders within a particular city.

Could you please help me with a query that accomplishes this task efficiently in ClickHouse?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly! To calculate the desired metrics efficiently in ClickHouse, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT
o.customer_id,
COUNT(*) AS total_orders,
c.city_id,
COUNT(*) AS orders_in_city,
COUNT(*) / o.total_orders AS order_percentage
FROM
(
    SELECT
        customer_id,
        COUNT(*) AS total_orders
    FROM
        orders
    WHERE
        order_date >= 'start_date' AND order_date <= 'end_date' -- Replace 'start_date' and 'end_date' with the desired time period
    GROUP BY
        customer_id
) o
JOIN
orders o2 ON o.customer_id = o2.customer_id
JOIN
districts d ON ST_Within(o2.latitude, o2.longitude, d.polygon) -- Assuming the polygon data is stored in the districts table
JOIN
cities c ON d.city_id = c.city_id
GROUP BY
o.customer_id,
c.city_id
HAVING
COUNT(*) > o.total_orders * 0.5
```

Here's a breakdown of the query:

The subquery o calculates the total number of orders for each customer within the specified time period. It groups the orders by customer_id and uses the COUNT(*) aggregate function.

The main query joins the orders table with the subquery o on the customer_id column. It also joins the districts and cities tables to get the city information for each order.

The ST_Within function is used to check if the latitude and longitude of an order fall within the polygon of the corresponding district.

The result is grouped by customer_id and city_id.

The COUNT(*) function is used to calculate the number of orders placed by the customer in each city.

The HAVING clause filters out customers who haven't placed more than 50% of their orders within a particular city.

Make sure to replace 'start_date' and 'end_date' with the actual start and end dates of the desired time period.

Comment: Copy-paste from ChatGPT